# How to change the src of an image

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

I tried to change the `src` of an image, but I can't to it with `getElementById`. Maybe there is some other way to do this ? 
This is the code that I'm trying:

```
let preview = document.getElementById('myImg').src = URL ;
```

Comment: *"doesn't work"* is a rather poor description of a technical problem ?

Comment: That code works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/n2qce9sp/ although you don't need the `let preview =` part. How exactly does it fail? Are you getting error messages? What's the value of `URL`? And why do we have to ask these questions in the first place?

Comment: Works fine as is, assuming you have a valid source and the code is running when the element is available in the DOM -> https://jsfiddle.net/v2zgguks/

Comment: @adeneo i don't why even the intelisence don't let me .src? it should be working

Comment: what is shown by intellisense is not a reliable indicator of what will work in all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use a type assertion you could also do something like this:

```
let img = document.getElementById('myImg');
if (img instanceof HTMLImageElement) img.src = URL;
```

This way if #myImg doesn't exist, or isn't an image, it won't try to change the src.

Answer (score 1):

simply using this

```
document.getElementById('myImg').src = URL ;
```

should work. If not, please provide your html code and more from your js, or check the console if there are any errors.

Comment: He probably means that the code the OP provided should work

Comment: @Denny - in that case, that should be a comment.

Comment: I'm working with angular, maybe it could be typescript vs javascript problem  ? i don't know

Comment: Yes, I mean that should work unless there is something else which breaks the code. I think we cannot help more without seeing more code.

Comment: there is anything else that i can put here about the code that may cause this error, i just know that even the intelisence show me .src, Angular2 problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let preview = document.getElementById('myImg');
preview.src = URL ;
```

hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

You could use the more modern `querySelector` if the browsers you are targeting allow for it:

```
document.querySelector("#myImg").setAttribute("src", URL);
```

Using the `src` property:

```
(<HTMLImageElement>document.querySelector("#myImg")).src = URL;
```